# Junit returning null pointer exception

Tags: java, junit, nullpointerexception, mockito

I am writing junit for the below case,

```
public void request (Message msg) {
    String s = msg.getPayload().getSerial();
}
```

Junit

```
@Test
public void requestTest() {
    Message msg = mock(Message.class);
    Mockito.when(msg.getPayload().getSerial()).thenReturn("tet"); --> This returns null
}
```

Any help

Comment: *"Any help"* (Do You Have) Any question?

Answer (score 3):

You have to also mock the payload:

```
@Test
public void requestTest() {
    Message msg = mock(Message.class);
    Payload payload = mock(Payload.class);
    Mockito.when(msg.getPayload()).thenReturn(payload);
    Mockito.when(payload.getSerial()).thenReturn("tet"); --> This returns null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `DEEP STUBS` ([`Mockito Docu`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS))

```
Mockito.mock(Message.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Note however that the `Mockito`dev's itself added a warning for it to the documentation:

> WARNING: This feature should rarely be required for regular clean code! Leave it for legacy code.

They explain that statement with a hint regarding the [`Law of Demeter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), so you could also think about adding a delegater method instead (if `Message` is actually an object under your control)